# iOS creating an app upgrade

Tags: ios, iphone, upgrade

The app I am working on is around 400Mb, the app itself is just 50Mb the rest is PDF files of manuals/wiring diagrams...

this app is just for my work and is used by myself and my colleagues. Since I am updating the app (correcting bug, adding new features) quite often, and it can be time consuming for all of us to download OTA 400Mb each time.

Is there any way to update only the app and to keep the document on the phone? Like first time we install the app, the download is 400Mb and then only 50Mb?

Thx.

Comment: Don't include the PDF files *inside* the app. On first launch, have the app download those PDF files from a server. On successive launches, check the server for updated / new PDF files and download as necessary. Then your app remains at its 50Mb size.

Comment: Great idea, I am already doing that with a json file. but I have a question, with the json file I have added a version umber at the top and I read and compare that version in order to download or not the file. With Pdf files, how can I check if there is a new document in the list or if the file has been updated but still has the same name? thank you!

Comment: Various ways to do it. One approach would be to create another json file (or add to the existing one) with a dictionary of the PDF files and date/time data. Compare that to a locally saved copy and download any PDFs with newer timestamps.

Comment: Will do that, Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see comment from DonMag for the answer to my question